# Error: rpc simulateTransaction error while trying to fetch quotes from Ray

Tags: transactions, private-node, simulate

For more context, this is for a trading bot being built around

1. Jupiter swaps
2. Raydium swaps using the Ray sdk

I often get this error while trying to fetch quotes from Ray.
And usually if I just fetch a quote the second time it works.

```
  reason: 'failed to simulate for instructions',
  code: 'RPC_ERROR'
```

I've tried Alchemy, Quicknode but they both give me this error, possibly due to receiving old blockhashes?

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: This lacks focus - it is really two questions. Rather than flag the question I've edited it to focus on the error. If you want to ask about ways to improve speed ask another question.

Answer (score 3):

This error means that your transaction is failing during the simulations checks.

you can skip using `skipPreflight: true` to see what the actual error is.