RPC_ERROR: failed to simulate for instructions
The full body of the error is:
    const error: any = new Error(message)
                       ^
Error: rpc simulateTransaction error
    at Logger.makeError (/home/nuh/Desktop/crypto_studies/node_swap/raydium-sdk-swap-example-typescript/node_modules/@raydium-io/raydium-sdk/src/common/logger.ts:213:24)
    at Logger.throwError (/home/nuh/Desktop/crypto_studies/node_swap/raydium-sdk-swap-example-typescript/node_modules/@raydium-io/raydium-sdk/src/common/logger.ts:225:16)
    at /home/nuh/Desktop/crypto_studies/node_swap/raydium-sdk-swap-example-typescript/node_modules/@raydium-io/raydium-sdk/src/common/web3.ts:267:21
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (/home/nuh/Desktop/crypto_studies/node_swap/raydium-sdk-swap-example-typescript/node_modules/@raydium-io/raydium-sdk/lib/cjs/common/web3.js:6:58)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  reason: 'failed to simulate for instructions',
  code: 'RPC_ERROR'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.

My code is below,
async sendVersionedTransaction(tx: VersionedTransaction, maxRetries?: number) {
    const txid = await this.connection.sendTransaction(tx, {
      skipPreflight: true,
      maxRetries: maxRetries,
    })

    return txid
  }

It seems that error caused by Liqudity.fetchInfo().
It is not deterministic and reported here
Do you have any idea what is wrong, and how can I handle the error?

Is really the place where the call fails? I just wonder as the skipPreflight should skip simulation and it should just serialize it and send on-chain. Or maybe some issue with web3.js library (e.g., recently maybe related fix of library https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/pull/2415
and/or https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9436/error-rpc-simulatetransaction-error-while-trying-to-fetch-quotes-from-ray

Had the same issue, answered here https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/9436/error-rpc-simulatetransaction-error-while-submitting-ray-swaps

@raydium-io/raydium-sdk/lib/cjs/common/web3.js
line 191: results = yield simulateTransaction(connection, transactions, batchRequest);
This method "simulateTransaction" getlatestdata from latestBlock,but some pool cannot dosn't have latest block data, so the simulationTransation return err,and throw.
Because this method is Promise,so when it throw err, hole process cannot caputure the error.
I comment the throw code.
